# Theories on why '_ ' variable suddenly stopped working in ipython jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

In python the "_" variable stores the result of the last expression...

However, for some reason in my copy of jupyter notebook, this feature suddenly stopped working when using sympy.  Anybody have any ideas what would cause the "_" to stop updating between commands?

[image: picture of problem]

So far I'm tried:

*reinstalling "active state python"
*restarting the jupyter server
*restarting kernal and rerun all.

Actually the reason why i'm wondering, because i tried this once below and then suddenly stopped working.. however, the ability to string together more than one command and see their output on each stop using '_' is too handy to stop using it just because it suddenly stops working... i'm wondering how to fix it...

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()

N=a*b*100 - (a**2) * (b**2)
D=2*(a-b)

V = N / D
V.diff(a)
_.simplify()
_.expand(numer=True)
_.expand(denom=True)
```

Comment: "Stopped working" is far too vague to diagnose.

Comment: I don't really understand why you would try use `_` that way at all anyway, but `sp.init_printing()` has a suspiciously apt name here; did you look at what that does?

Comment: I don't use Jupyter Notebooks, but on REPL, if nothing was printed from the previous statement, then nothing is stored in `_`. Assignments don't print anything... On another note, what's wrong with doing `display(N)`, `display(D)`, and `display(V)`?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there's anything wrong with your Jupyter Notebook. There's simply a misunderstanding with how the interactive console works.

Let's investigate this funky `_`.

```
>>> 1+1
2                #  output printed stored in _
>>> _
2
>>> a = 10+10    #  output not printed and therefore not stored in _
>>> _
2            
>>> a
20               #  output stored in _
>>> _
20
```

This leads one to believe that if nothing is printed into the console, then the value isn't stored in `_`. But now...

```
>>> print(1)
1
>>> _
20               #  gives previous output
```

This then suggests that if nothing is *returned*, then the value isn't stored in `_`. (Remember, the `print` function returns `None`.)

So what's going on in your code?

```
N=a*b*100 - (a**2) * (b**2)    #  assignment, no result returned => nothing stored in _    
D=2*(a-b)                      #    ditto

V = N / D                      #    ditto
V.diff(a)                      #  returns an instance of <class sympy.core.add.Add> => stored in _    
_.simplify()                   #  returns an instance of <class sympy.core.mul.Mul> => stored in _    
_.expand(numer=True)           #    ditto
_.expand(denom=True)           #    ditto
```

I think you can see what's up with your first snippet now...

```
N=a*b*100 - (a**2) * (b**2)    #  blunder! nothing is returned => nothing stored in _    
display(_)                     #    oops
D=2*(a+b)                      #  blunder!
display(_)                     #    oops
V = N / D                      #  blunder!
display(_)                     #    oops
```

Instead, make sure that a value is returned.

```
a*b*100 - (a**2) * (b**2)      #  result returned => value stored in _
display(_)                     #  ok
N = _                          #  ok, retained N
```

The foolproof way to *fix* this would be to do use `N`, `D`, and `V` in lieu of `_`:

```
N=a*b*100 - (a**2) * (b**2)
display(N)                     #  ok
D=2*(a+b)
display(D)                     #  ok
V = N / D
display(V)                     #  ok
```

Time to stop being lax and time to start using those variable names. ᕕ(◔ω◔)ᕗ

Comment: ok... I get it... I'm misunderstanding how python "_" variable works... it only stores it in this variable if you haven't already save it to a variable....  the act of assigning it to a variable redirects the object to the variable and doesn't display it.

Answer (score 0):

If you had ever written to (assigned to) "_", you would be effectively creating one more variable with the same name, which thereafter "hides" or takes precedence over the pre-defined variable "_". And of course, the "_" that you define doesn't get the magical behavior of storing the last computed expression value, as happens with the predefined "_".

If this is what had happened, this might get corrected by performing one or both of the following:

1. del _ # Deletes the "_" that you had defined.
2. Re-starting the kernel in your notebook.

Comment: @roganjosh: When I type an underscore between double-quotes, and submitted to SO, the underscore mysteriously vanishes, leaving just the double-quotes. I realized that after the submission. Tried escaping the underscore with a backslash - thankfully that worked.

Comment: Surrounding text with underscores on either side will italicize it. I guess that's what's going on and very unfortunate for writing this answer :P